# Triangle inequality on p-norm with $0<p<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $\|x\|_p=(\sum^n_{k=1}|x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$. Then how to prove the
triangle inequality on p-norm with $0<p<1$

And I know the one inequality

for $a,b\ge 0, a+b\le  (a^p+b^p)^\frac{1}{p}\le 2^{(1-p)p} (a+b)$

Comment: You will struggle to prove this because the triangle inequality doesn't hold for $0 < p < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n$ is even ( can be extended for odd $n$ too ), now consider $\mathcal{x}$ vector with $1$ in the even indexed positions and $0$ in the odd indexed positions. Let $\mathcal{y}$ vector with $0$ in the even indexed positions and $1$ in the odd indexed positions. For the triangle inequality to hold we must have that $\|x+y\|_p \le \|x\|_p+\|y\|_p$ therefore $n^{\frac{1}{p}} \le 2(\frac{n}{2})^{\frac{1}{p}}$ which is impossible since $2^{\frac{1}{p}} > 2$ for $0 < p < 1$ and we have a counterexample.